# HTML doesn't render in production buld of an expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building an quiz app. And each quiz has thoery that is stored in html files.
These html files are for displaying content. I am using 'react-native-render-html' package for rendering the HTML content. When I run my app with Exp Go app  on android, it render the html file content, but when I build an apk file and run on my android phone, I got blank screen, the html file content doesn't appear.

This is my code, it is working fine on expo go app.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RenderHtml from "react-native-render-html";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Modal,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  useWindowDimensions,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

import Icon from "./Icon";
import colors from "../utility/colors";


const TopicSummary = ({ isVisible, onClose, topicId }) => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const contentFileName = "../assets/topicIntro/article.html";


  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to read HTML content from the asset file
    const readHtmlFile = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const asset = Asset.fromModule(contentFileName);
        const response = await fetch(asset.uri);
        const html = await response.text();
        setHtmlContent(html);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error reading HTML file:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

      readHtmlFile();
  }, [isVisible]);

  return (
    <Modal visible={isVisible} animationType="slide">
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {loading && <ActivityIndicator color={"blue"} size={"large"} />}
         
          <RenderHtml
            source={{
              html: htmlContent,
            }}
            contentWidth={width}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does it work when you initialize ```htmlContent``` with static html like
```const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("<html>...</html>");``` ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl  Yes, it works.

Comment: Is there a way to load html content from HTML files?

Comment: I guess there is thrown exception in your try/catch block, check what exception is thrown in when using an apk ?
Maybe you need to add the permission ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />```
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/network-ops/connecting

Comment: The exception was thrown when I used `asset.uri` , but when I changed it to `asset.localUri` it worked.  The `asset.uri` was trying to access files from expo server, and it was working on expo go app. But when when I installed apk file on my phone, it still tried to fetch files from expo server, that is why I got error.   Thank you for your prompt response.